# Ember js using name for URL slug

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to use another field in the URL? I would like to use the name but I have apply toLowerCase() first which I'm doing in the specific object. Here's my code. Everything works but the object data doesn't show up in the view... Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LayerSpark</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">{{#linkTo 'categories'}}Categories{{/linkTo}}</li>
                <li>{{#linkTo 'help'}}Help{{/linkTo}}</li>
                <li>{{#linkTo 'account'}}Account{{/linkTo}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
                {{outlet}}

    </div>

</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories">

    <div  {{bindAttr class=":row"}}>
        <div {{bindAttr class=":col-lg-4"}}>
            <ul>
                {{#each model}}
                <li>{{#linkTo 'category' slug}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div {{bindAttr class=":col-lg-8"}}>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="category">
   Post:<br>
    My name is :: {{ categories.name }}<br>
    My id is :: {{id}}<br>
    My slug is :: {{slug}}<br>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories/index">
    <p class="text-warning">Please select a Category</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="help">
    <p class="text-warning">Help me</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="account">
    <p class="text-warning">Your bank account is ...</p>
</script>
```

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS:true
});
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
    category: "categories"
});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: '/api'
    })
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('categories', function() {
        this.resource('category',{path:':category_slug'});
    });
    this.resource('help');
    this.resource('account');
});

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Category.find();
    }
});
App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, category) {
        controller.set('model', category);
    }
});

var attr = DS.attr;

App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    slug: function(){
        return this.get('name').toLowerCase();
    }.property('name')
});


Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('markdown', function(input) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('date', function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to hook into the `serialize` hook of your `CategoryRoute` and provide there the slug.

Example:

```
App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, category) {
    controller.set('model', category);
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {
        category_slug: model.get("name").toLowerCase()
    };
  }
});
```

This way you can remove also the slug computed property in your model, and in your links you then do:

```
{{#each model}}
  {{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tried that but in my links, I was using "name" not "this" so it didn't work.

Comment: As a follow up question, do you know why deep linking wouldn't be working? For example, if I go to /#/categories/name directly. The page is blank. Do I need a dependency in the controller?